Finding a witness vector that maximizes the dot product with a vector compared to rest of the vectors.
Image of Algorithm description:

Hello all, I am trying to program a computational algorithm that optimizes the above problem, in the image.
Basically given a set of vectors belonging to set S and a vector p, we need to find a witness vector n such that, the dot product of n & p is maximum as compared to all other vectors in S.
When I am computationally modeling this, I am getting infeasible model, as there is no bound on vector n.
I am not aware of any known algorithm that actually solves this linear time. The author of the paper guarantees that a witness vector n can be found in linear time.
Does anyone have any idea regarding this ?

What is a "witness vector?"  That is a non-standard term.

@Paul there is no particular definition of witness vector in the paper, its can be think of a vector that maximizes the vector p in some direction compared to all other vectors q, or I could be wrong, if the word "witness" has some other context, that I am not aware of.

Is $E$ finite?  Do you have a small numerical example?

@RobPratt yes E is finite. I have also updated the algorithm image description. You can think of any basic numerical example, related to convex combination, as an example for finding witness vector.

A linear programming (LP) problem to express $p\in S$ as a convex combination of points $e_i \in E$ is to minimize $0$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i e_i \lambda_i &= p \\
\sum_i \lambda_i &= 1 \\
\lambda_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$} 
\end{align}
If the problem is infeasible, the LP dual variables provide a certificate of infeasibility.

I have actually modeled this for convex combination algorithm part. What I am having trouble is with the witness algorithm part, I am not able to model the maximize of dot product of n & p compared to all other vectors q in set E. I dont think this can be modeled using convex combination algorithm.

The dual variables provide the certificate/witness.

Aaah ok,  I see, I believe I was not understanding the language properly, the dual variables when a point is not convex combination provides the witness vector, but is there any way to retrieve these dual variables from a model when it is not feasible ? I am trying to implement this in gurobi library in python, but there is not a way to retrieve dual variables when model is infeasible. Any idea on this ?

I don’t use that library, but some LP solvers provide a dual ray to certify infeasibility or a primal ray to certify unboundedness.

Alright, got it, I will look into the library then, to retrieve this dual ray. Thank you for your answer.
